# Extract text in BeautifulSoup except for one tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to extract text using BeautifulSoup.

Here is the html :

```
<div>
    "BLABLA"
    <span> "RRRRR" </span>
    <span> "ZZZZZ" </span>
</div>
```

I would like to get only `'BLABLA'` and `'RRRR'` and get ride of `'ZZZZ'`

Of course `soup.text` gives me the 3 texts.

One solution would be to iterate until I find the second span (as in this question : [How to get all text between just two specified tags using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808776/how-to-get-all-text-between-just-two-specified-tags-using-beautifulsoup))

But is there a nicer solution in this case ?

Comment: Why method that you found won't work? Regex is an option

Comment: It would work. I'm just wondering if there is a nicer solution if in this case (that is not the same as in the solution I found).

Comment: If you have exactly that html, then you can do something like this: `soup.div.contents[0]` and `soup.div.span.text`. If no there is no nicer way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code (which you can modify as per your needs):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = '''
<div>
    "BLABLA"
    <span> "RRRRR" </span>
    <span> "ZZZZZ" </span>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

wanted_text = [x.strip() if isinstance(x, NavigableString) else x.text.strip() for x in soup.find('div').contents[:2]]
print(wanted_text)
# ['"BLABLA"', '"RRRRR"']
```

If the HTML changes a bit, you simply have to change the indices for slicing (i.e change `contents[:2]` to whatever you need).