# Pull text between two BeautifulSoup elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

The overall question has been asked and answered in a few places:
http://www.resolvinghere.com/sof/18408799.shtml

[How to get all text between just two specified tags using BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808776/how-to-get-all-text-between-just-two-specified-tags-using-beautifulsoup)

But in trying to implement, I am getting really cumbersome strings.

My setup:
I'm trying to pull transcript text from the Presidential debates, and I thought I'd start here: http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111500

I can isolate just the transcript with

```
transcript = soup.find_all("span", class_="displaytext")[0]
```

The formatting of the transcript isn't ideal.  Every few lines of text has a `<p>` and they denote a change in speakers with a nested `<b>`.  eg:

```
<p><b>TRUMP:</b> First of all, I have to say, as a businessman, I get along with everybody. I have business all over the world. [<i>booing</i>]</p>,
<p>I know so many of the people in the audience. And by the way, I'm a self-funder. I don't have — I have my wife and I have my son. That's all I have. I don't have this. [<i>applause</i>]</p>,
<p>So let me just tell you, I get along with everybody, which is my obligation to my company, to myself, et cetera.</p>,
<p>Obviously, the war in Iraq was a big, fat mistake. All right? Now, you can take it any way you want, and it took — it took Jeb Bush, if you remember at the beginning of his announcement, when he announced for president, it took him five days.</p>,
<p>He went back, it was a mistake, it wasn't a mistake. It took him five days before his people told him what to say, and he ultimately said, "It was a mistake." The war in Iraq, we spent $2 trillion, thousands of lives, we don't even have it. Iran has taken over Iraq, with the second-largest oil reserves in the world.</p>,
<p>Obviously, it was a mistake.</p>,
<p><b>DICKERSON:</b> So...</p>
```

But like I said, not a new problem.  Define a start and end tag, iterate through the elements, as long as current != next, add the text .

So I'm testing on a single element to get the details right.

```
startTag = transcript.find_all('b')[165]
endTag = transcript.find_all('b')[166]
content = []
content += startTag.string
content
```

And the results I get are `[u'R', u'U', u'B', u'I', u'O', u':']` instead of `[u'RUBIO:']`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to find all `b` elements inside the transcript, then get each of the `b` element's parents and find next paragraphs until there is one with `b` element inside. Implementation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
import requests

url = "http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=111500"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
transcript = soup.find("span", class_="displaytext")
for item in transcript.find_all("b")[3:]:  # skipping first irrelevant parts
    part = [" ".join(sibling.get_text(strip=True) if isinstance(sibling, Tag) else sibling.strip()
                     for sibling in item.next_siblings)]
    for paragraph in item.parent.find_next_siblings("p"):
        if paragraph.b:
            break

        part.append(paragraph.get_text(strip=True))

    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
    print("\n".join(part))
    print("-----")
```

Prints:

```
DICKERSON:
Good evening. I'm John Dickerson. This holiday weekend, as America honors our first president, we're about to hear from six men who hope to be the 45th. The candidates for the Republican nomination are here in South Carolina for their ninth debate, one week before this state holds the first-in-the-South primary.
George Washington ...
-----
DICKERSON:
Before we get started, candidates, here are the rules. When we ask you a question, you will have one minute to answer, and 30 seconds more if we ask a follow-up. If you're attacked by another candidate, you get 30 seconds to respond.
...
-----
TRUMP:
Well, I can say this. If the president, and if I were president now, ...
```